# Event after all fields filled

Tags: javascript, angular, events, ionic3

I have 4 inputs and 1 button which is disabled

```
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<input type="button" disabled="true">
```

How I can remove attribute disabled from button after all fields will be filled. Something another events oninput and onchange.

Comment: What is the point? Why not to use the best suitable event for the purpose?

Comment: @Teemu is it right to validate it after all inputs in input? Event on change will be bad cause its only for mobiles

Comment: That depends on .. but in generally yes. `onchange` only for mobiles? That's some malinformation, desktop browsers have implemented `onchange` as well.

Comment: @Teemu No. I mean my task will be using only for mobiles. And to click somewhere for triggering `onchange` event on mobiles will be inconveniently

Comment: [disabled]="condition" and change condition value on inputs' (keydown)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using FormGroups

> app.component.html

```
     <form [formGroup]="mygroup" >

           <input type="text" formControlName="input1">
           <input type="text" formControlName="input2">
           <input type="text" formControlName="input3">
           <input type="text" formControlName="input4">

           <input type="button" disabled="true" type="submit" [disabled]="!mygroup.valid">
        </form>
```

> app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {Validators, FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';


export class FormsPage {
  private mygroup : FormGroup;

  constructor( private formBuilder: FormBuilder ) {
    this. mygroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      input1: ['', Validators.required],
      input2: ['', Validators.required],
      input3: ['', Validators.required],
      input4: ['', Validators.required],
    });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the ionic validation

https://ionicframework.com/docs/developer-resources/forms/

Look for this line and its example:

```
<button ion-button type="submit" [disabled]="!todo.valid">Submit</button>
```